# How many 3 letter words containing a,b are there in S? S= a,b,c,d,e

Tags: probability

Three-letter words are generated randomly from $5$ characters: a,b,c,d,e where letters can be used at most once.

(a) How many three-letter words are there in the sample space S? $5*4*3$ (I'm good with this)

(b) How many words containing a,b are there in S? (This I can't figure out)

In the solution, it says to select the two indices of the locations to place. 
This can be done in $2*3$ ways. There remains one position to be filled with c,d or e. Therefore the number of words is $3*6 = 18$

I know that if you're looking for the permutations where a word starts with a particular letter you do $(n-1)!$ but i really don't know how to apply it to this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly as the solution key suggests, you should approach this via multiplication principle.  Remember that if you can perfectly describe each outcome uniquely as a sequence of questions/answers with a particular number of options at each step, then the total number of outcomes is the product of the number of options at each step.

> *How many three-letter words exist using letters available from a,b,c,d,e such that they contain both the letter a and the letter b and each letter is used at most once*?

- Step one: We know that our word will have letters $a$ and $b$.  Pick what the remaining letter is.  It will be one of $c,d,$ or $e$ for a total of $3$ choices.
- Step two: Pick the order in which the letters appear.  There are $3!$ choices.  Note, this is *regardless* of what the letter picked in step one is.

As a result, there are $3\cdot 3! = 18$ possible three-letter words satisfying the above conditions.

Specifically, they are $abc, abd, abe, acb, adb, aeb, cab, dab, eab, bac, bad, bae, bca, bda, bea, cba, dba, eba$

---

More details for step two: Why is it $3!$?

This can also be shown using multiplication principle.  (*In fact, most early counting questions can be broken down as some combination of multiplication principle, addition principle, and inclusion-exclusion*)

- Step 2a:  Pick the location of the $a$.  It will either go in the first available space, the second available space, or the third for a total of three options.
- Step 2b:  Pick the location of the $b$.  Depending on where the $a$ was placed, there will be two options for where the $b$ can go remaining.  Note, this is *regardless* of *where specifically* the $a$ was placed.  Although the *specific options* have changed, the *number* of options has not.

At this point, the remaining extra letter will be placed in the unused location, whichever was not used by $a$ and $b$.  There are then $3\cdot 2=3!$ number of arrangements of the three letters.

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic explanation! It's clear now.